# Action bar menu icon not showing on right position but show in dropdown

Tags: android

I am trying to add menu icon on the Android action bar in design view I can see the menu on right position but when I try to preview it's not showing when set to `app:showAsAction="always"` its show as the hidden dropdown. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

**Design view**

[image]

**APP Running preview**

[image]

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:icon="@drawable/outline_home_white_48"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Home">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_option"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon"
    android:title="Options"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:title="@string/action_settings">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_update"
            android:title="@string/update_app">
        </item>
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

**My java code**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle action bar actions click
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            default:

        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**Android build version**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.aaa"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  `android:showAsAction` instead of `app:showAsAction`. 
Also add `tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"`

I have solved it here is the full code

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:icon="@drawable/outline_home_white_48"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Home"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon_white"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search Branch"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_option"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon"
    android:title="Options"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:title="@string/action_settings">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_update"
            android:title="@string/update_app">
        </item>
    </menu>
</item>
```